# What are the pros and cons of using AWS CodePipeline vs Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, aws-codepipeline

What are the pros and cons of using AWS CodePipeline vs Jenkins?

I can't see a whole lot of info on the interwebs (apart from https://stackshare.io/stackups/jenkins-vs-aws-codepipeline). As far as I can see they are as follows:

AWS CodePipeline Pros

- Web-based
- integrated with AWS
- simple to setup (as web-based)

AWS CodePipeline Cons

- can't be used to set up code repos locally

Jenkins Pros

- standalone software
- can be used for many systems (other than AWS)
- many options for setup (e.g. plugins)
- can be used to setup code repos locally

Any other major differences that people can use to make an informed choice?

Comment: Should that be 'cloud-based' rather than 'web-based' ?

Comment: AWS CodePipeline cost peanuts. Does a full-time devops engineer to manage Jenkins cost peanuts?

Answer (score 8):

CodePipeline is a continuous "deployment" tool, while Jenkins is more of a continuous "integration" tool.

Continuous integration is a DevOps software development practice where developers regularly merge their code changes into a central repository, after which automated builds and tests are run.

With continuous deployment, code changes are automatically built, tested, and released to production. Continuous deployment expands upon continuous integration by deploying all code changes to a testing environment and/or a production environment after the build stage.

*References:*
https://aws.amazon.com/devops/continuous-integration/
https://aws.amazon.com/devops/continuous-delivery/

Comment: This answer may have been accurate at the time, but it certainly less correct now. CodePipeline allows chaining different CodeBuild stages which can perform integration - builds, tests, integration tests, deployments to pre-prod and prod stages. That said, CodePipeline is missing many features Jenkins achieves with plugins - deployment rollbacks, postponing deployments to specific time windows to name a few major ones.

Answer (score 6):

Other downside of using AWS CodePipeLine is lack of integration with source control providers other than GitHub. The only other option we have is to create version enabled Amazon S3 bucket and push our code there. This creates an extra layer between Source control and CodePipeline.

Also, there is no proper documentation available to explain how one could push their code to Amazon S3 bucket for codebases built in commonly used platforms such as .Net. The example given in AWS website deals with some random files which is not helpful whatsoever.

The other entry(trivial?) missing in your question from *cons* section of AWS CodePipeLine is, Price. Jenkins is free.
Gitlab SCM solution is now provided by AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/

Comment: Free ? You have to host it, so it is not free. Typically hosting + maintenance will cost you more than $1/month which is the AWS CodePipeline price.

Comment: It's worth noting that Amazon AWS now has CodeCommit which integrates with CodePipeline as a source control provider.

Comment: I am finding it hard to integrate Gitlab as it does not support it for now.

Comment: This is now out of date as CodePipeline now supports Bitbucket, GitLab, GitLab Self-Managed, and GitHub Enterprise Server.

Answer (score 4):

CodePipeline and Jenkins can accomplish the same thing. Also you don't have to necessarily use the web UI for CodePipeline it can be setup through an AWS SAM CLI template, very similar to CloudFormation templates.

CodePipeline also supports a lot of source code providers, AWS CodeCommit, AWS S3, GitHub, and BitBucket.

I personally like CodePipeline a lot better than Jenkins if your working in AWS. The interface is 10x cleaner IMO. And with the SAM CLI templates your pipelines can be managed as code, similar to how you'd use a Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot more with Jenkins because you can customize it with a myriad plugins. Thus, you can stay on the bleeding edge, if needed.
By contrast, with Codepipeline you are limited to what AWS offers you. Of course, Codepipeline gives you the opportunity to select Jenkins as the tool for the build step. However, that means you cannot use Jenkins for different purposes at other stages of the pipeline.
If you are fan of Hashicorp Vault, you can easily integrated with Jenkins to provide dynamic secrets to your builds. You cannot do that with Codepipeline. you will have to rely on the Cloud-native mechanisms, in this case AWS KMS.

Here is a tutorial that shows you how to integrated Jenkins with Codepipeline - you will need several plugins to get Jenkins to talk to the different Codepipeline components.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-by-integrating-jenkins-with-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codedeploy/